# SankeyNetwork in R package NetworkD3 not finding sankey with minimal crossings

Tags: r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I am using the sankeyNetwork function to create a diagram of very simple flow data. Even using multiple iterations, the resulting diagram has obviously unnecessary crossovers.

I ran this code in R Studio 2023.06.2+561  with R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16).

```r
library(networkD3)
source<-c(0,1,2,0)
target<-c(3,3,4,4)
value<-c(13320, 274, 10950, 96000)
links<-data.frame(source, target, value)
nodes<-data.frame(names=c('Solar', 'Wind', 'Natural Gas', 'Electricity', 'Hydrogen'))
p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "names", iterations=32, 
                   units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30, sinksRight = FALSE)
```

The resulting Sankey Diagram has an obviously avoidable crossing: if "Wind" were above "Solar" then there would be no crossings. I've tried 1000 iterations and it doesn't do anything - which has me wondering if the issue is the platform or R Studio -- since 1000 iterations should be slower than 1.

[Resulting Sankey Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD1sC.png)

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain why exactly d3-sankey doesn't avoid that crossover, but if you change the order of your data (and don't bother messing with the iterations) you can avoid it...

```r
library(networkD3)
source<-c(1,0,2,1)
target<-c(3,3,4,4)
value<-c(13320, 274, 10950, 96000)
links<-data.frame(source, target, value)
nodes<-data.frame(names=c('Wind', 'Solar', 'Natural Gas', 'Electricity', 'Hydrogen'))
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "names", 
              units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30, sinksRight = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the dataset will only get more complicated from here, so while this solution works for this limited case, it isn't generalizable to a more complex set of flows. I'm wondering if there's a problem with my code or the environment in which I'm running it. Can anyone else get the function to order these differently in the diagram using the original order in the dataframe?

Comment: I tried the same data on an Observable notebook forked from D3’s example sankey and got the same result, so I don’t think it’s going to be any different in any other environment (unless there is customized code to sort nodes in a specific way).